# Qual a melhor maneira para desenvolver ícones para aplicacativos Android?

Tags: android, ícone

Qual a melhor maneira para desenvolver ícones nos aplicativos Android?

<kbd>[image: Exemplo icones []</kbd>

Comment: A melhor maneira para desenvolver os ícones é desenhando-os!

Answer (score 1):

Se você estiver usando IDE Android Stúdio ele ja tem uma ferramenta que converte imagem para ícone... nesse caso você vai em:

botão direiro na pasta app > New > Image Asset (lá você importa a imagem e ele ja converte para ícones) espero te ajudado!

Comment: No Eclipse se a pessoa instalou tudo que precisa pra desenvolver aplicativo android da maneira certa, na hora de configurar o projeto também aparecem opções para os ícones. À propósito, como emulador sugiro usar o Genymotion.

Answer (score 1):

É no Phophotoshop
É um programa profissional e nele você terá todas as ferramentas necessárias para conseguir produzir ícones a nível profissional.